# How to resize square children widgets after parent resize in Qt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qgridlayout

I want to do board with square widgets. When I run code it creates nice board but after resize it become looks ugly. I am trying resize it with resize Event but it exists (probably some errors). I have no idea how to resize children after resize of parent.

Children widgets must be squares so it is also problem since I can not use auto expand. Maybe it is simple problem but I can not find solution. I spend hours testing different ideas but it now works as it should.

This what I want resize (click maximize):
[image]

After maximize it looks ugly (I should change children widget but on what event (I think on resizeEvent but it is not works) and how (set from parent or children cause program exit).

[image]

This is my minimize code:

```
import logging
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QPaintEvent, QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGridLayout


class Application(QApplication):
    pass


class Board(QWidget):
    def square_size(self):
        size = self.size()
        min_size = min(size.height(), size.width())
        min_size_1_8 = min_size // 8
        square_size = QSize(min_size_1_8, min_size_1_8)
        logging.debug(square_size)
        return square_size

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        square_size = self.square_size()

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(0)

        squares = []
        for x in range(8):
            for y in range(8):
                square = Square(self, (x + y - 1) % 2)
                squares.append(squares)
                square.setFixedSize(square_size)
                grid.addWidget(square, x, y)
        self.squares = squares
        self.setLayout(grid)

    def resizeEvent(self, event: QtGui.QResizeEvent) -> None:
        # how to resize children?
        logging.debug('Resize %s.', self.__class__.__name__)
        logging.debug('Size %s.', event.size())
        super().resizeEvent(event)


class Square(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, color):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        if color:
            self.color = QtCore.Qt.white
        else:
            self.color = QtCore.Qt.black

    def resizeEvent(self, event: QtGui.QResizeEvent) -> None:
        logging.debug('Resize %s.', self.__class__.__name__)
        logging.debug('Size %s.', event.size())
        super().resizeEvent(event)

    def paintEvent(self, event: QPaintEvent) -> None:
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        painter.fillRect(self.rect(), self.color)
        painter.end()


def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    app = Application(sys.argv)
    app.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)

    default_font = QFont()
    default_font.setPointSize(12)
    app.setFont(default_font)

    board = Board()
    board.setWindowTitle('Board')
    # ugly look
    # chessboard.showMaximized()
    # looks nize but resize not works
    board.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How should I do resize of square children to avoid holes?

### 2nd try - improved code but still I have not idea how to resize children

Some new idea with centering it works better (no gaps now) but still I do not know how to resize children (without crash).

After show():

[image]

Too wide (it keeps proportions):

[image]

Too tall (it keeps proportions):

[image]

Larger (it keeps proportions but children is not scaled to free space - I do not know how to resize children still?):
[image]

Improved code:

```
import logging
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QPaintEvent, QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout


class Application(QApplication):
    pass


class Board(QWidget):
    def square_size(self):
        size = self.size()
        min_size = min(size.height(), size.width())
        min_size_1_8 = min_size // 8
        square_size = QSize(min_size_1_8, min_size_1_8)
        logging.debug(square_size)
        return square_size

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        square_size = self.square_size()

        vertical = QVBoxLayout()
        horizontal = QHBoxLayout()

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(0)

        squares = []
        for x in range(8):
            for y in range(8):
                square = Square(self, (x + y - 1) % 2)
                squares.append(squares)
                square.setFixedSize(square_size)
                grid.addWidget(square, x, y)
        self.squares = squares

        horizontal.addStretch()
        horizontal.addLayout(grid)
        horizontal.addStretch()
        vertical.addStretch()
        vertical.addLayout(horizontal)
        vertical.addStretch()
        self.setLayout(vertical)

    def resizeEvent(self, event: QtGui.QResizeEvent) -> None:
        # how to resize children?
        logging.debug('Resize %s.', self.__class__.__name__)
        logging.debug('Size %s.', event.size())
        super().resizeEvent(event)


class Square(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, color):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        if color:
            self.color = QtCore.Qt.white
        else:
            self.color = QtCore.Qt.black

    def resizeEvent(self, event: QtGui.QResizeEvent) -> None:
        logging.debug('Resize %s.', self.__class__.__name__)
        logging.debug('Size %s.', event.size())
        super().resizeEvent(event)

    def paintEvent(self, event: QPaintEvent) -> None:
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        painter.fillRect(self.rect(), self.color)
        painter.end()


def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    app = Application(sys.argv)
    app.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)

    default_font = QFont()
    default_font.setPointSize(12)
    app.setFont(default_font)

    board = Board()
    board.setWindowTitle('Board')
    # ugly look
    # chessboard.showMaximized()
    # looks nice but resize not works
    board.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How should I resize square children without crash?

Comment: Just remove the call `square.setFixedSize(square_size)`?

Comment: As G_M points out, don't just put a fixed size on it, since by default the widgets take up as much space as possible and as are similar widgets then they will expand in the same proportion, but they will be stretched as rectangles and you say you want square. How do you expect them to be square if in many cases the width and height of the window are not equal?

Comment: @G.M. Without size it expand to rectangle but should be square.

Comment: @eyllanesc I want to make square board with square squares. This board should be scalable and centered probably apart grid layout I should use hbox and vbox to center it - graphics will be svg. I do not know how to do in qt5 (I can do it in html and ...) but it is possible to do.

Comment: Normally I will read parent size and resize children but it not works or I do not know how to resize children and on which event I should do it. When I do it in resizeEvent it crash.

Comment: Note in case you use this and it does not work for you -- I am saying that after the little adjustments and changing that method call I got it to work cleanly

Comment: @DennisJensen I am still solving but I do some progress first of all I was added `excepthook` to see exception. I found that resizing works from resizeEvent of parent (I do bug in adding to list of squares invalid values). After it I can resize children but it still now works maybe because of margins.

Comment: @DennisJensen When I resized children parent was expanding forever maybe it because there was some `ContentsMargins` and I do not use it in calculations or not properly set. I do not know how it works because if it not set it reports no margins but there is margins and when I set it margins is dropped - I will soon study this case (I will return to it today night).

Comment: @Chameleon When resizeEvent is called the widget (and its children) already has been resized, so you should never resize widgets within a resizeEvent reimplementation, or you'll probably always face a recursion (hence the "expanding forever") even if you're really careful with contents margins. By the way, check your code because you added the `squares` list to itself in the for cycle.

Comment: @musicamante squares cycle is simple bug but after adding excepthook I track it without problem. Where is the best place for resize code it resizeEvent generates cycle (I suspect by long programming experience intuition but I am new in qt5 so was not sure and very blind like baby which see but not recognize anything). I am starting studying your great examples below so may there is answer where to place adjusting/resizing code.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should never "automatically" resize anything whenever you have a layout, as the layout should take care of it: Qt makes advanced computation of each widget size hints and size policies, with some widgets even changing their hints according to the space the layout provides them (like labels or textedits); in certain situations there could be dozens of continuous calls to size hints before the widgets are actually "mapped" and finally shown. For these reasons, the best and safest way to do this is to subclass the layout.

Comment: Some information about how Qt handles layouts: http://kdemonkey.blogspot.com/2013/11/understanding-qwidget-layout-flow.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible solution.
You can use the [Graphics View framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html), which is intended exactly for this kind of applications where custom/specific graphics and positioning have to be taken into account, otherwise create a layout subclass.
While reimplementing a layout is slightly simple in this case, you might face some issues as soon as the application becomes more complex. On the other hand, the Graphics View framework has a steep learning curve, as you'll need to understand how it works and how object interaction behaves.

### Subclass the layout

Assuming that the square count is always the same, you can reimplement your own layout that will set the correct geometry based on its contents.

In this example I also created a "container" with other widgets to show the resizing in action.

When the window width is very high, it will use the height as a reference and center it horizontally:
[image: window very wide]

On the contrary, when the height is bigger, it will be centered vertically:
[image: window very tall]

Keep in mind that you should **not** add other widgets to the board, otherwise you'll get into serious issues.
This would not be impossible, but its implementation might be much more complex, as the layout would need to take into account the other widgets positions, size hints and possible expanding directions in order to correctly compute the new geometry.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Square(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, color):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        if color:
            self.color = QtCore.Qt.white
        else:
            self.color = QtCore.Qt.black
        self.setMinimumSize(50, 50)

    def paintEvent(self, event: QtGui.QPaintEvent) -> None:
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.fillRect(self.rect(), self.color)


class EvenLayout(QtWidgets.QGridLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setSpacing(0)

    def setGeometry(self, oldRect):
        # assuming that the minimum size is 50 pixel, find the minimum possible
        # "extent" based on the geometry provided
        minSize = max(50 * 8, min(oldRect.width(), oldRect.height()))
        # create a new squared rectangle based on that size
        newRect = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, minSize, minSize)
        # move it to the center of the old one
        newRect.moveCenter(oldRect.center())
        super().setGeometry(newRect)


class Board(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        layout = EvenLayout(self)
        self.squares = []
        for row in range(8):
            for column in range(8):
                square = Square(self, not (row + column) & 1)
                self.squares.append(square)
                layout.addWidget(square, row, column)


class Chess(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        header = QtWidgets.QLabel('Some {}long label'.format('very ' * 20))
        layout.addWidget(header, 0, 0, 1, 3, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.board = Board()
        layout.addWidget(self.board, 1, 1)

        leftLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(leftLayout, 1, 0)
        rightLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(rightLayout, 1, 2)
        for b in range(1, 9):
            leftLayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Left Btn {}'.format(b)))
            rightLayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Right Btn {}'.format(b)))

        footer = QtWidgets.QLabel('Another {}long label'.format('very ' * 18))
        layout.addWidget(footer, 2, 0, 1, 3, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Chess()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### Using the Graphics View

The result will be visually identical to the previous one, but while the overall positioning, drawing and interaction would be conceptually a bit easier, understanding how Graphics Views, Scenes and objects work might require you some time to get the hang of it.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Square(QtWidgets.QGraphicsWidget):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()
        if color:
            self.color = QtCore.Qt.white
        else:
            self.color = QtCore.Qt.black

    def paint(self, qp, option, widget):
        qp.fillRect(option.rect, self.color)


class Scene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.container = QtWidgets.QGraphicsWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QGraphicsGridLayout(self.container)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.container.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.addItem(self.container)
        for row in range(8):
            for column in range(8):
                square = Square(not (row + column) & 1)
                layout.addItem(square, row, column, 1, 1)


class Board(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        scene = Scene()
        self.setScene(scene)
        self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        # by default a graphics view has a border frame, disable it
        self.setFrameShape(0)
        # make it transparent
        self.setStyleSheet('QGraphicsView {background: transparent;}')

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        # zoom the contents keeping the ratio
        self.fitInView(self.scene().container, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)


class Chess(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        header = QtWidgets.QLabel('Some {}long label'.format('very ' * 20))
        layout.addWidget(header, 0, 0, 1, 3, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.board = Board()
        layout.addWidget(self.board, 1, 1)

        leftLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(leftLayout, 1, 0)
        rightLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(rightLayout, 1, 2)
        for b in range(1, 9):
            leftLayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Left Btn {}'.format(b)))
            rightLayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Right Btn {}'.format(b)))

        footer = QtWidgets.QLabel('Another {}long label'.format('very ' * 18))
        layout.addWidget(footer, 2, 0, 1, 3, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Chess()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I will study this example maybe today night. BTW I like chess :)

Comment: I've added another solution I forgot to insert in the first place. The approach is very different (as it doesn't involve layouts at all and requires learning graphics view/scenes), but might be more appropriate for a program that uses graphic elements such as this one.

Comment: I want to try second approach after first it looks that it can be better after studing some other code. I started from widget since it looks simple to start but many implementation use scene maybe becacuse it easier to render.

Comment: I tested second version and has little bug with initialization - not centralizes board at open but it works after resize. Thank for help it is great examples how to code board+++. You help me much in saving my life time :)

Comment: That's strange. It might depend on the platform. Maybe you can invalidate() the layout just after the first time it's shown (within the showEvent or the resizeEvent of the main window) and see if something happens. Otherwise, you could try with updateGeometry(), sometimes it helps.

Comment: I try to learn more Qt5 now my skill in it is level 1 (beginner) and in programming level 7 (master) :) Problem was found in Windows 10/Python 3.8. I start learning Qt5/Qt4 from `https://github.com/lukasmonk/lucaschess`. If you like chess see Lucaschess there is very nice application with focus on training but not only. In this application scene is used. Only problem is that is coded in Python/Spanish (looks like shorter version of Latina) so you need both learn Qt4 and Spanish. Spanish is nice but it takes time.